# Gulp: how to compose tasks sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I would need to compose gulp tasks by sequentially processing different sources as there are dependencies between them.

Based on the documentation this should be done my merging streams but I see no way on how to enforce to order and serialize them.

What is the proper way to model this in Gulp 3 ?

I typically use functions as containers for the individual build steps and then invoke them from the build and watch tasks:

```
function buildModule(module) {
    var streams = [];

    // step one
    streams.push(
        gulp.src(path.join('./modules', module, '*.js'))
        // ... series of chained calls
    );

    // step two
    streams.push(
        gulp.src([TMP, ...])
        // generate target also using some of the files from step one
        );

    return eventStream.merge(streams);
}

gulp.task('build:A', [], function () {
    return buildModule('A');
});

gulp.task('watch:buildModule', [], function () {
    gulp.watch('./modules/**/*.js', function (event) {
        if (event.type === 'changed') {
            return buildModule(path.basename(path.dirname(event.path)));
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch:buildModule'], function () {});
```

Comment: why not use gulp-sequence

Comment: @entre Generally speaking, because if only want to use tasks where they are needed and actually describe an actually entity of work to be done.

Comment: @materialdreams Couldn't you just `.pipe` the results of one stream to the other that depends on it? Why do you need to manually manage the synchronization?

Comment: @Asad  For reasons of simplicity I've used the comment "// ...generates TMP" as a placeholder for a series of chained calls that generate a temporary set of files in a first step. The second step then uses some of the files generated in the first step and some others files as source and uses a completely different series of chained calls to generate the final target files.

Comment: @materialdreams Ok, so you have a stream of files that you've piped through some preprocessing. Let's call this `var stage1_1 = gulp.src(...).pipe(foo()).pipe(bar())...`. You want to use the files from `stage1_1` stream, as well as the files from some other, parallel work, and pipe them all through some more steps. You can do `var stage1_2 = gulp.src("./myauxilaryfiles/*.*").pipe(some()).pipe(more()).pipe(processing())`. And then finally `var final = merge(stage1_1, stage1_2).pipe(my()).pipe(final()).pipe(processing());`. `merge` here is `var merge = require('merge-stream');`.

Comment: Note that there's just one stream throughout.

Comment: @asad I'm not sure I understand. Let's stay with my example where everything including the merging works as expected except for the fact that step2 does not wait for step one to finish. How can I enforce that?

Comment: @materialdreams You can't have multiple streams and still expect them to be sequential. In your example, instead of adding that first stream to `streams`, store it in variable. Then, create another stream representing the extra files you want to pass into step2. Now you need to merge these two streams and pass them into the second stage. You need to require the `merge-stream` module, and invoke the function you get with the two aforementioned streams. Then, do all the stage2 processing on this merged stream. Hopefully that makes sense?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are basically three ways to do that.

#### 1. Defining dependent tasks

Gulp allows developers to define dependent tasks by passing an array of task names as second arguments:

```
gulp.task('concat', function () {
    // ...
});

gulp.task('uglify', ['concat'], function () {
    // ...
});

gulp.task('test', ['uglify'], function () {
    // ...
});

// Whenever you pass an array of tasks each of them will run in parallel.
// In this case, however, they will run sequentially because they depend on each other
gulp.task('build', ['concat', 'uglify', 'test']);
```

#### 2. Using run-sequence

You can also use [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) to run an array of tasks sequentially:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
    runSequence('concat', 'uglify', 'test', cb);
});
```

#### 3. Using lazypipe

Although Lazypipe is a library to create reusable pipelines, you can somehow use it to create sequential tasks. For example:

```
var preBuildPipe = lazypipe().pipe(jshint);
var buildPipe = lazypipe().pipe(concat).pipe(uglify);
var postBuildPipe = lazypipe().pipe(karma);

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('**/*.js')
        .pipe(preBuildPipe)
        .pipe(buildPipe)
        .pipe(postBuildPipe)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: Options 1 and 2 are clearly the way to go when composing tasks with tasks and is generally the way to go but is not what I was actually looking for. For me it's about the granularity of tasks and (at least) in my use case I would end up with an incredible number of (private) tasks instead of composing the tasks using streams and then having the tasks doing what they are supposed to be doing.
Option 3 looks promising but stream-series seams to be a simpler solution for what I'm trying to do.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This little module may help: [stream-series](https://github.com/rschmukler/stream-series).

Just replace `eventStream.merge(streams)` with:

```
var series = require('stream-series');
// ...
return series(streams);
```